# can not make an API in my express server for the strip payment checkout

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, stripe-payments

i get this error:

> Uncaught (in promise) IntegrationError: Invalid value for stripe.confirmCardPayment intent secret: value should be a client secret of the form ${id}*secret*${secret}. You specified: client secret.

*##"client secret is default value" I need to update it and console need to display *actual client secret**

**backend code**

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const express = require("express")
const cors = require("cors");
const stripe = require("stripe")(
    "secret_key"

);

const app = express();

app.use(cors({
    origin: true
}));
app.use(express.json());

app.get("/", (request, response) => response.status(200).send("hello payment"));


app.post("/payments/create", async (request, response) => {
    const total = request.query.total;

    console.log("Payment Request Recieved >>> ", total);
    console.log(stripe)
    const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
        amount: total,
        currency: "usd",
    });


    response.status(201).send({
        clientSecret: paymentIntent.client_secret,
    });
});

// - Listen command
exports.api = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

**calling api in payment js**

```
useEffect(() => {

    const getClientSecret = async () => {
        const response = await axios({
            mehtod: 'post',


            url: `/payments/create?total=${totoalItemPrice(basket) * 100}`
        })


        setClientSecret(response.data.clientSecret)

    }
    getClientSecret();

}, [basket])

console.log('THE SECRET IS >>>', clientSecret)
```

Comment: Edit your question and include Call confirmation code. The code is unreadable in comments.

Comment: Also I would suggest console.log(paymentIntent.client_secret) & console.log(paymentIntent). Make sure you are setting the PaymentIntent's client_secret field (which looks like "pi_123_secret_123"), not the PaymentIntent's ID (which is "pi_123"). Just check and confirm if you setting the right value in stripe.confirmCardPayment()

Comment: Refer to this [document](https://stripe.com/docs/js/payment_intents/confirm_card_payment) to see the method parameters. clientSecret should be string. Also check @cicada_'s answer. I think it can be one of the reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sever code is returning :

```
response.status(201).send({
    clientSecret: paymentIntent.client_secret,
});
```

But on client side you're expecting it to be in format :

```
setClientSecret(response.data.clientSecret)
```

when I logged it to console, response object looked like :

```
{"clientSecret: "pi_someHashValueHere"}
```

Either you can modify server side code to send :

```
response.status(201).send({
    data: { clientSecret: paymentIntent.client_secret }
});
```

or modify it on client side. currently you're accessing an undefined value hence the IntegrationError that you're getting.

Comment: thanks for explaining such a nice way, but when I logged in to console, I did not see any client secret in hashvalue formate...instead it displays default secret client value:true

Answer (score 1):

Ensure you are confirming the card payment in the frontend with:

```
const paymentConfirmation = await stripe.confirmCardPayment(
    client_secret,
);
```

Comment: card confirmation code :const handleSubmit =async(event) =>{
    
    event.preventDefault()
    setProcessing(true)

    
    const payload =await stripe.confirmCardPayment(clientSecret,{
        payment_method:{
            card:elements.getElement(CardElement)
        }
    }).then(({paymentIntent})=>{
//payment intet ==payment confirmation

setSucceeded(true)
setProcessing(false)
setError(null)
//history.replace("/order")
navigate.replace("/orders")
console.log("order")

    })
}

Comment: payment confirmation code is written still not working